# Creating trigger between two different schemas table in one DB?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

I've been working on a database which consists of two schemas names as front and backup. Where in one table name:

```
front.Details

    studID SemID GPA
    100     1     4
    200     2     3
```

Another table name is:

```
backup.DetailsV
studID  DEPT SemID GPA
```

I need to create a trigger on Table front.Details when there is insert all rows must be inserted in to Table backup.DetailsV twice with deptC column twice.

The output in Table backup.DetailsV should look like below:

```
studID  DEPT SemID GPA
100      1     1    4
200      1     2    3
100      2     1    4
200      2     2    3
```

How can I create trigger on table A to insert twice with dept id 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger
ON Front.Details
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO backup.DetailsV (Dept, SemID, GPA)
   SELECT 1, SemID, GPA FROM INSERTED
   INSERT INTO backup.DetailsV (Dept, SemID, GPA)
   SELECT 2, SemID, GPA FROM INSERTED
END
```

Note that we are SELECTing from the special INSERTED table twice, and inserting twice, once each with the required departments.